# Python NewsApiClient

Tags: python, google-api, google-news

I am trying to retrieve news using the GoogleNews API. When I search through my script, it often happens that I don't find any articles. If I search manually, I often find a lot of articles. I know that the ads are limited to 30 days old articles (at least in the developer News API).

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

def find_articles(lst_of_keywords):
    article_lst = [False] * 5
    keywords = []
    for keyword in lst_of_keywords:
        if keyword:
            keywords.append(keyword)
    print(keywords)
    api = NewsApiClient(api_key=API_KEY)
    all_articles = api.get_everything(q=' '.join(keywords),
                                      sort_by='publishedAt',
                                      language='de')
    print(all_articles)
    print('Keywords:', ', '.join(keywords), '\n', 'Total results: ', str(all_articles['totalResults']), '\n')
    num_article = 0
    for article in all_articles['articles']:
        print(article['title'] + ' - ' + article['source']['name'])
        print(article['url'])
        print(article['content'], '\n')

        num_article += 1
        if num_article == 5:
            break
name = False

find_articles(["HOWOGE Wohnungsbaugesellschaft mbH   Bau Wohnungen"])
```

My Results:

```
['HOWOGE Wohnungsbaugesellschaft mbH   Bau Wohnungen']
{'status': 'ok', 'totalResults': 0, 'articles': []}
Keywords: HOWOGE Wohnungsbaugesellschaft mbH   Bau Wohnungen 
 Total results:  0
```

When I check the news.google.com:

[Screenshot_GoogleNews_Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMpzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

After check [these](https://github.com/News-API-gh/News-API-python/issues/6)<sup>1</sup> [entries](https://github.com/mattlisiv/newsapi-python/issues/62)<sup>2</sup> in Github, it seems no solution has been made.

My suggestion is:

- Change the search terms by leaving *less* keyworks.

I tried this request:

URL: `http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=HOWOGE&apiKey=<YOUR_API_KEY>&language=de`

> Search terms: **`HOWOGE`**
>
> language: **`de`**

And I got these results:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 2,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bild",
                "name": "Bild"
            },
            "author": "Bild.de",
            "title": "Investor fehlt - 1000 Wohnungen in Berlin in der Warteschleife",
            "description": "Die Genehmigungen liegen vor, der Generalunternehmer ist unter Vertrag, selbst die Namen der neuen Straßen stehen. Doch das Wichtigste fehlt: der Investor.",
            "url": "https://www.bild.de/regional/berlin/berlin-aktuell/investor-fehlt-1000-wohnungen-in-berlin-in-der-warteschleife-72304654.bild.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.bild.de/5f3043e4728dd70001396d5b/6d502ebc7a2f82d9f87de35b0c150aa2/1/1?w=1280",
            "publishedAt": "2020-08-10T13:23:03Z",
            "content": "Berlin Die Genehmigungen liegen vor, der Generalunternehmer ist unter Vertrag, selbst die Namen der drei neuen Straßen stehen bereits fest. Das Wichtigste aber fehlt: Der Investor für die mehr als 10… [+1460 chars]"
        },
        {
            "source": {
                "id": "bild",
                "name": "Bild"
            },
            "author": "Bild.de",
            "title": "Mit interaktiver Tabelle - In Berliner Schulen wird in den Ferien geschuftet",
            "description": "Klassenarbeiten in den Ferien, für Handwerker selbstverständlich! An 243 Berliner Schulen wird derzeit saniert und erweitert.Foto: Michael Hübner / nurfotos.de",
            "url": "https://www.bild.de/regional/berlin/berlin-aktuell/mit-interaktiver-tabelle-in-berliner-schulen-wird-derzeit-geschuftet-71969242.bild.html",
            "urlToImage": "https://images.bild.de/5f144438789c220001bc4f2b/1d98a2419bc2a53a3dc764fd67ae7bbf/1/1?w=1280",
            "publishedAt": "2020-07-20T05:24:14Z",
            "content": "Berlin Klassenarbeiten in den Ferien für Handwerker selbstverständlich! An 243 Berliner Schulen wird ohne Pause saniert und erweitert. Dächer, Fassaden, Fenster, Fußböden, Elektroleitungen, Sanitäran… [+4462 chars]"
        }
    ]
}
```